# Drupal pathauto URL alias not being created correctly for revision

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am having a very frustrating problem with a Drupal publishing workflow implementation.
When new content is created as a revision and put into a workflow state and remains unpublished the URL path settings > Automatic alias is not being created correctly.
For example my new content has a title of 'tasty cheddar' and is placed in the menu under 'cheese' and 'english', the generated URL would be: 'cheese/english/tasty-cheddar'.
Instead the URL being generated is that of the parent menu it, in this example it would be 'cheese/english-0', 0 is appended as the URL alias already exists.

To summarise, URL alias is not being created when Content is saved as a revision opposed to being Published.

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Pathauto? There are some fixes in the recent version related to workflow and revisions. Have you considered posting in the Pathauto issue queue on Drupal.org?

Comment: Hi Matt, I will update Pathauto now and try again.

Comment: No luck with update, it seems to have made pathauto perform even worse! It's not replacing spaces with hyphens or transforming to lowercase as specificied in settings. Have update.php and also re-saved settings. Reverting to previous version. Help!

Answer (score 0):

[Workbench Path Revision](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_path_revision) module should solve this. It provides versioning of path aliases.

We are using this module in our project to have versioning of path aliases.